# Rewriting specific Strings within a text file and appending the rest

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to append an array of strings onto my text file but I also want to rewrite the first line each time too.

This is how I save my text (I attempted to append):

```
public static void saveText (String[] studentArray, String assignArray [], String fileName, int numStudents) throws IOException {
    File dumpFile = new File(fileName + ".txt");
    if (!dumpFile.exists()) {
        dumpFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (dumpFile, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);

    bw.write(Integer.toString((int)numStudents));
    bw.newLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
        bw.write(studentArray[i]);
        bw.write(", ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < assignArray.length; i++) {
        bw.write(assignArray[i]);
        bw.write(", ");
    }

    bw.close();
    System.out.println("SUCCESFULLY DUMPED FILE");

}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?  What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: My apologies, i can see how it wouldn't seem clear. I want to be able to append student and assignment information (the arrays) onto this file. However, I do not want want to append the number of students. I want it to be so that the number of students updates by replacing the old number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) if you want to insert into your file. I've never actually used this because to be perfectly honest I find it easier to rewrite the existing file.

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm using the text file as a database to store and access information on students.  Thanks for the answer though!  I will try using RandomAccessFile.